# How to convert a value to a string inside a loop for in a template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want do the following:
In the tamplate *candidate_list* I list all of candidates registered, and I must show the candidate average beside of him, but the average of a candidate are saved in another model (Evaluation).So I try put a loop for inside the loop for that shows the candidate (Candidate) and in this second loop for he search the *Evaluation* that have the attribute *candidate*(it's a ForeignKey) and compare with the *candidate.name*, witch is taken in the extern loop for, but the *candidate.name* is a string and the evaluation.candidate is a ForeignKey, and I thought in convert this attribute to a string and compare, but I don't really know how do this, I tried the following:

**template: candidate_list.html**

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lista de candidatos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <link href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="/"> Lista de candidatos: </a></h1>
    {% block content %}
        {% for cand in candidates %}
            <p>
            <div><a href="{% url 'candidate_detail' pk=cand.pk %}">Nome:{{ cand.name }}</a></div>
            <!--<div id="average">Média:{{cand.average}}</div>-->
            </p>
            {% for e in eva %}
                {% if e.candidate |stringformat:" "  == cand.name %}
                    <p>{{ e.score }}</p>
                {% endif %} 
            {% endfor %}        
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidate, Criterion, Evaluation
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm
from .forms import EvalForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def canditate_list(request):
    candidates = Candidate.objects.all()

    eva = Evaluation.objects.all()
    eval_cand_list = []                                     #aqui guarda uma lista com os FK candidates convertidos p/ str

    context = {
        'candidates': candidates,
        'eva': eva
    }
    return render(request, 'app/candidate_list.html',context)

def candidate_detail(request, pk):
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pk=pk)
    c_name = candidate.name                                 #pega o nome (string) do candidato
    c1 = Evaluation.objects.all()                           #guarda tds Evaluation na variavel  
    scores = []                                             #declara a array que vai receber as notas
    for c in c1:                                            
        cand = str(c.candidate)                             #guarda o nome do candidato do Evaluation atual
        if cand == c_name:                                  #confere se o Evaluation atual corresponde ao candidate atual(pk)
            scores += [c.score]

    _sum = 0                                                #variavel que guardara a soma declarada
    for s in scores:
        _sum += s                                           #faz a soma dos scores

    average = 0 
    if len(scores) > 0:
        average = _sum/len(scores)                              #tira a média

    context = {
        'candidate': candidate,
        'average': average
    }



    return render(request, 'app/candidate_detail.html', context)

def evaluation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)

        if form2.is_valid():    
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('canditate_list') 

    else:
        form2 = EvalForm()
        return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,})


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('candidate_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CandForm()
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField
from site_.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class Criterion(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default = '')
    github = models.URLField(default = '')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100, default = '')
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default = '')
    higher_education = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    average = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    #############################################################score = models.ForeignKey()
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/media', null=True, blank=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Evaluation(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, unique=True)
    criterion = models.ForeignKey(Criterion, default='')
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    appraiser = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.candidate)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change to string format to get details from Evaluation as name in Candidate is a foreign key. I believe the below code should work fine.

```
{% for e in candidate.evaluation_set.all %}
    <p>{{ e.score }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's work well,thank you very much.. But, you can explain me what exactly is 'candidate.valuation_set.all'...it's a template tag,right?

Comment: Please accept the answer as this will add points to my kitty.  Please refer to "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/"